# Configuration for Istanbul and mocha Node js code coverage

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I am new to Istanbul and mocha Framework.

for my Node.js project i am configuring mocha and Istanbul.

it works fine separately.

i don't have an idea how to integrate both and produce the coverage report.

I found some of the documentation or configuring in Package.json Script for Mac.

But i need to set up for windows machine.

i have spent enough time researching on my own but i didn't find any perfect doc for it,Can someone help with the proper documentation would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts to be added in package.json for windows :

```
"scripts": {
        "coverage": "istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test/*.js",
        "test": "mocha  test/*.js"
    }
```

Command to run the Coverage with UnitTesting :

```
npm run coverage
```

Command to run only the Test Cases:

```
npm run test
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Istanbul website:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc mocha"
  }
}
```

https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/mocha/